# Calculate SUM from avg of max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to calculate the data three times in one query.
here is the example table :

> ```
> Date#####| Time   |  Week  |  MachineID |   Value | Type
>  1408_1  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    2    | Alert
>  1408_1  | 1408_1_2 |  1408  |  001 |    4    | Alert
>  1408_2  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1408_2  | 1408_1_2 |  1408  |  001 |    6    | Alert
>  1408_3  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    7    | Alert
>  1408_3  | 1408_1_2 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1408_4  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    8    | Alert
>  1408_4  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1408_5  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |   10    | Alert
>  1408_5  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1408_6  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    12   | Alert
>  1408_6  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1408_7  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    14   | Alert
>  1408_7  | 1408_1_1 |  1408  |  001 |    5    | Alert
>  1409_1  | 1409_1_1 |  1409  |  002 |     9   | Alert
>  1409_1  | 1409_1_1 |  1409  |  003 |   14    | Alert
> ```

assume I have a lot of data, I have : 
1. for each week, there are 7 date (1-7), 
2. for each date, there are several time (1-2),
3. for each time, there are several machine operated (001 - 003)

here is the expected result from the example above :

> ```
> WEEK  | Value   |
>  1408  |  61      |   --> the data already complete for this week
>  1409  | 14       |
> ```
>
> .....UP TO 7 WEEK
>
> First, I take the maximum data for each group by, (let say: group based on machineID)
>
> Second, I calculate the average of that maximum number for each other group,  (group based on date-in this case the date only 1 - 7)
>
> Third, I SUM the average calculation before for each other group again, (group based on Week).

so there is three group and three select,,,

I want to display top 7 week based on ASCENDING order...

here is my code so far :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT TOP 7 week, CAST(SUM(AP) as float) as [apLW], CAST(AVG(AR) AS FLOAT) AS [ARlw] FROM (SELECT TOP 7 WEEK, CAST(SUM(MaxScoreP) as float) AS [SP], CAST(AVG(MaxScoreP) as float) AS [AP], CAST(SUM(MaxScoreR) as float) AS [SR], CAST(AVG(MaxScoreR) as float) AS [AR] FROM " & _
     "(SELECT [date] AS DATE_, [machineID], week, MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Alert' THEN CAST(JL as float) END) as [MaxScoreP], MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'ROLL-OUT' THEN CAST(JL as float) END) as [MaxScoreR] FROM tbl_tablename GROUP BY Week, [date], [machineID] ) AS m GROUP BY [Week] ORDER BY [Week] DESC) X GROUP BY [Week] ORDER BY [Week] ASC"
```

that code works fine up to the second select statement, but for the third select (SUM) seems error, because it doesn't change the result. 
do you have any suggestion about my problem.

EDITED CODE:

```
        Dim strCommand As String = " SELECT WEEK, date_, CAST(SUM(MaxScoreP) as float) AS [SP], CAST(AVG(MaxScoreP) as float) AS [AP] FROM " & _
                                "(SELECT [date] AS DATE_, [machineID], WEEK, MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'PILOT' THEN CAST(JL as float) END) as [MaxScoreP] FROM " & _
                                "tbl_TBL_NAME GROUP BY WEEK, [date], [machineID] ) AS m GROUP BY [WEEK], [Date_] ORDER BY [WEEK] DESC"
```

up to this point, I am able to get the average for each date of all data. do you have any suggestion what should I do next to group it and get the result for each week?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your expected output? on your 2nd part you already select top 7 records, so it will return only 7 records, what make you think it can further perform another average? if possible create a schema in sqlfiddle, it help the response

Comment: @ah_hau yeah, you were right... but I can't get ascending order for the result if I didn't put top 7 in that select... I am sorry, I never used sqlfiddle before, but I have type some data table above. see the edited...

Comment: show sample output also

Comment: if using `TOP n` you MUST use an ORDER BY, otherwise you may not get what you expect

Comment: thanks for the data, now tell us what you expect as a result...

Comment: @Used_By_Already I added the expected result... see the edited..

Comment: @Sathish I have added the expected result... edited...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for comment.

Your outermost query achieves no change to the data because it is already grouped by [Week] before you reach that outermost layer - and there simply isn't anything new in that layer.

Below I suggest a change in how you do your top 7, and have removed the redundant outermost layer.

```
SELECT
      [Week]
    , CAST(SUM(MaxScoreP) AS float) AS [SP]
    , CAST(AVG(MaxScoreP) AS float) AS [AP]
    , CAST(SUM(MaxScoreR) AS float) AS [SR]
    , CAST(AVG(MaxScoreR) AS float) AS [AR]
FROM (
            SELECT
                  [date]                                                     AS DATE_
                , [machineID]
                , tbl_tablename.[Week]
                , MAX(CASE
                        WHEN [Type] = 'PILOT' THEN CAST(JL AS float) END)    AS [MaxScoreP]
                , MAX(CASE
                        WHEN [Type] = 'ROLL-OUT' THEN CAST(JL AS float) END) AS [MaxScoreR]
            FROM tbl_tablename
                  INNER JOIN (
                              SELECT TOP 7
                                    [Week]
                              FROM tbl_tablename
                              GROUP BY
                                    [Week]
                              ORDER BY
                                    [Week] DESC
                        ) AS w7
                              ON tbl_tablename.[Week] = w7.[Week]
            GROUP BY
                  tbl_tablename.[Week]
                , [date]
                , [machineID]
      ) AS m
GROUP BY
      [Week]
ORDER BY
      [Week] ASC
```

---

*note* your sample data does not contain all the fields used by this query, and while having data is a great start knowing what you want as a result is what we also need.

Comment: I follow your suggestion, modified it based on my problem and I get the result... Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it...

Comment: Great! I believe you accept the answer to indicate completion.

Comment: yeah,,, with some modification it can be used to get the answer... so I will mark it as an answer.. thanks for the help..